# Chrome + Tor + Proxy Switchy!

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, tor

Chrome 7 keeps showing a dialog saying: `514 Authentication Required` when I use TOR.

How I solve this?

Comment: Did you follow these directions?...http://lifehacker.com/5614732/create-a-tor-button-in-chrome-for-on+demand-anonymous-browsing

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem.
Chrome shows me the following message: 514 Authentication Required, when using Proxy Switchy! extension with Tor.
Help ME!

Answer (score 7):

I found this to work: I have the Tor Bundle installed which is Firefox 7 + Tor. To make Chrome work with it I did this on Windows:

I created a shortcut to Chrome, right-clicked on the shortcut > Properties. There on the Shortcut tab in the Target field is the address of the executable, like:

```
C:\Chrome\chrome.exe
```

Add the proxy details after it so it looks like:

```
C:\Chrome\chrome.exe --proxy-server=";socks=127.0.0.1:9051;sock4=127.0.0.1:9051;sock5=127.0.0.1:9051" --incognito check.torproject.org
```

This will set it to use SOCKS proxy on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) on port `9051` (not sure where this is set, Tor's settings seem to use that), and `check.torproject.org` is just the address it will open with.

Answer (score 3):

You tried to use Tor as a http proxy. Tor isn't a http proxy!

2 solutions :

1 (the best) - install a private web proxy likes polipo ou privproxy, proxy switchy will control this setup (chrome/web proxy on top of tor)

2 - you configure chrome to use a socks proxy (in the panel options/under the hood/change proxy settings/internet propriety/lan settings/proxy server/advanced/servers, fill the socks fields with the tor settings : localhost and the tor's port)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the HTTP space empty.  Only fill in the localhost for the socks.  The IP is hidden successfully.